# iOS Push Notification Badging

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications, voip

I have an iOS voip app that is always running in the background. I have successfully implemented push notifications and am able to badge the app icon from the didReceiveRemoteNotification method. However, I only see a badge on the icon if the app is fully open when the notification arrives. Closing the app then results in a badge representing the current badge count.

The app is never not running so I have not determined if the icon would be badged when a notification is received in that case.

When the app is running in the background (which is almost all the time) and a notification is received the user sees the default notification banner that remains visible for about 5 seconds then is gone. At that point the only way for a user to see the notification is be going to Notification Center (swiping down from the top of the screen). The icon never gets badged.

First, is this the normal behavior? If so, is there any way to get the icon badged when running in the background?

Comment: I think it is normal I have the same problem too, but somehow some developers managed to solve this, which u can see on many games and apps as well

Comment: you may check `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` when app is running in background, not very sure though.

Comment: when you send push notification, specify the badge number in "aps" -> "badge", the app should be able to update badge number automatically.